# Showing error Main class not found

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

I am new to Java. I want to run a project in Netbeans.

I downloaded a project and opened with netbeans. When running it, netbeans says 
`project does not have a main class set` and it is showing warning as 
`package javax.servlet.*` does not exists.

Why is it showing these errors? and how to run the project correctly in netbeans?

Kindly clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 2):

> *Why is it showing these errors?*

The error message says everything :)

---

To set main class of project in netbeans,

> right click the project > properties > in categories, select run > on the right side you can see option to set the main class.

[image]

---

In regards to `javax.servlet.* is does not exist.` ,

> For developing servlets, just make sure that the JAR file containing javax.servlet.* is in your CLASSPATH. Servlets are not the part of JAVA SE API. So you have to download separately and set your CLASSPATH accordingly.

---

Also read this [article.](http://www.sitepoint.com/java-servlets-1/)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to run a web project. In that case you have to deploy your project on a web server and run the project on the browser.